# Node, Sinon - unable to test constructor agruments

Tags: node.js, chai, sinon

I need to test/assert the constructor call with expected arguments while calling a function but getting an error `AssertError: step1,step2 is not a function`. I'm using sinon, chai libraries for testing function in nodejs

```
// pipeline.js
class Pipeline {
  constructor(steps) {
      this.steps = steps;
  }

  run(data) {
      console.log('run steps with data');
  }
}
```

```
// job.js
function peformJobs(data, steps) {
  const pipeline = new Pipeline(steps)
  pipeline.run(data)
}
```

```
// jobs.test.js
const sinon = require('sinon');
const Pipeline = require('./pipeline')
onst peformJobs = require('./job')
describe('test performJobs function', () => {
  it('should call pipeline with step1, step2', () => {
    sinon.spy(Pipeline, 'constructor');
  
    const data = { some: 'data' };
    const steps = ['step1', 'step2']
    peformJobs(data, steps)
  
    // want to test Pipeline constructor called with the required arguments or not
    sinon.assert.calledWithNew(steps)
  });
});
```

Comment: I think what you are trying to do is problematic for two reasons. 1. It is not simple to stub a class constructor - see: https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/issues/1892; 2. It is not simple to stub a dependent module of an imported module - see: https://sinonjs.org/how-to/stub-dependency/

Comment: got it. My only concern here is that I just need to assert constructor called with expected steps or not because unit test cases are already covered for each step separately and don't want to duplicate the tests again. can we achieve the same using any other library?